# webview : how to handle javascript code from multiple web pages

Tags: android

In a WebView, how do you access the JavaScriptInterface from multiple web 
pages, and not just from the page that you load via mWebView.loadUrl("http://10.241.139.45:9081/amexco/login.html")

e.g.

In my project's assets folder, I have:

```
login.html
page1.html
page2.html
```

... and here is the relevant WebView code:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "android");
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

So at different points in time, a user may look at index.html, page1.html, etc. From what I can tell, only the JavaScript in index.html has access to the JavaScriptInterface via "window.android.someMethodName()". When I try to make a call to "window.android.someMethodName()" from page1.html, it says that "window.android" is not defined.

so the user starts the webview from 
login.html page and navigates through different pages..
my requirement is in the last page of my webpage i have a button saying return to android  activity. so when user clicks on the last page of my navigation the user has to come back to the android activity.

window.android.someMethodName()" can be called in html page which works fine. but this method will work if i call this method only from the first page which i loaded ie from the login.html page only this method will work.. if i call this method from the last page of the webview naviagation this is not working.

Can any one help me out in this.

Comment: Do you need the javascript only to get back to the activity?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `window.`. If you are injecting a virtual global named `android`, you call methods on it as `android.someMethodName()`.

Also, make sure that you are viewing your subsequent Web pages in the `WebView`. By default, links bring up the user's default Web browser, which will not have your injected virtual global.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. But can you please write me any code snippet sample to handle events of multiple pages in android.

Comment: @user626570: There is no "code snippet". Your registered JavaScript interface should work regardless of what is loaded in the `WebView`. That is registered on a per-`WebView` basis, not a per-page basis.